# The popup should not open on home page with elementor

Tags: elementor

I am trying to open the register popup on home page but should not open. but the popup open on another page, what is the suggestion for this problem?

Comment: I have similar problem. Did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the plugin, try to deactivated the plugin one by one.
I used the hover plugin, if i deactivated that plugin the popup is work correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Consider adding more details (such as a link to the specific hover plugin) to help future users with the same issue.